# How to get modified attribute by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a function that change data attribute of the element by ajax.

Next time I want to get modified data attribute of the same element, but I got a value of the previous data attribute although attribute was changed.

So, What am i doing wrong?

Example:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".class1").on("click", function(){
     var attribute_data = $(this).data("attribute");
     $.ajax({
       ... // Handle
       success:function(data){
           $(this).data("attribute") === "2";
       }
     });
   }); 
  
  
  
  $(".class1").on("click",function(){
    var modified_attribute_data = $(this).data("attribute");
    console.log(modified_attribute_data); // will return "1" instead "2"
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1" data-attribute="1">
  Content
 </div>
```

Comment: You trigger both "onclick" at the same time, so ajax don't get the chance to finish before the console gets call and log.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? Right now you have two click handlers for the same element `$(".class1")`?

Comment: Omg, both of you right - thank you. It's my mistake. But I don't know how to create a trigger. Can you give me a link to read about it for my situation or just write here?

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
$(".class1").on("dblclick", function(){
      $(this).hide();
      var attribute_data = $(this).data("attribute");
      $.ajax({
         ... // Handle
         success:function(data){
         $(this).data("attribute") === "2";
         $(this).show();
      }
   });
});
```

and then click:

```
  $(".class1").on("click",function(){
    var modified_attribute_data = $(this).data("attribute");
    console.log(modified_attribute_data); // will return "2"
  });
```

I recommend separating the events that trigger it each one, or somehow blocking one or the other like toggling a class... and remember ajax is asynchronous, so dont expect it to be instantly change...